# .htaccess - регулярные выражение любых символов

Tags: php, .htaccess

пытаюсь сделать ЧПУ ссылки. Вроде всё получалось, до одного момента:

```
https://example.com/posts/Looking-to-buy-Adult-traffic-??/226
```

Если в регулярном выражении есть **?** - запрос крашится и получается 404.

Все остальное ссылки в виде:

```
https://example.com/posts/Forex-/-Crypto-traffic-available/154
```

Работают правильно.

Сейчас правильно работает вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?sub=$1&rid=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?sub=$1&rid=$2
```

И вроде бы должно работать правильно, т.к. **(.*)** - любые символы, пробовал так же **([^/]*)**, но увы, результат такой же. Работают все ссылки, кроме тех, где есть **?**.

Как я понял, у меня есть одно решение, которое должно помочь - закодировать знак вопроса в `%3f` с помощью php, но можно ли решить эту проблему не прибегая к такому решению?

**UPD**:

Что бы Работало решение @teran, нужно включить AllowEncodedSlashes, однако, после включения все ссылки ведут на error 500, пробовал так же добавить ключ [B], но это тоже не работает, поскольку нужно AllowEncodedSlashes, в общем получается замкнутый круг, разорвать который, пока что не представляю как...

```
Note that you may also need to set AllowEncodedSlashes to On to get this 
particular example to work, as httpd does not allow encoded slashes in URLs,
and returns a 404 if it sees one.
```

Написано на официальном сайте

Comment: а вам вообще это соответствие из `$1` для работы  нужно? что-то мне кажется, что смысл имеет только id который передается в `rid`.

Comment: @teran , да в принципе - нет. Но всё равно нужно, что бы оно так было

Comment: оба ваших правила кстати сводятся в одно, если просто сделатете `/?` в конце.

Comment: такс. че то я в ответе шляпу какую-то написал, так что удалил. У в вашем URL, все что после первого вопроса, очевидно рассматривается как GET-параметры. удаляйте из вообще из URL. либо кодируйте.

Comment: @teran , хорошо, буду удалять, большое спасибо за ответ